# Не работают media запросы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,900');
*{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.top-menu a{
    font-size:14px;
    color: #5f5f5f;
}
.top-menu li{
    position:relative;
}

.top-menu li+li:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:15px;
    width:1px;
    background-color:#999;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top:17px;
}

.top-menu a:hover{
    color:#0c7ff6;
}
.callback {
   padding: 15px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   float: right;
}
.line{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.middle{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.middle input[type=search]{
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 15px;
}
.search{
    position: relative;
}
.fa-search{
    color:#0c81f6;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    right: 20px;
    top:20px;
    position: absolute;
}

/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {


/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}


/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .top-menu a{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="top-menu col-sm-10 nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Сотрудничество</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Гарантия</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="callback col-sm-2" href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="container middle">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-2">
                <a  href="#"><img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-1">
                    <form class="search" action="">
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск...">
                        <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </header>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

media.css подключены после style.css, не пойму в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пропустили закрывающую скобку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получили выражение, которое невозможно (`max-width : 768px and min-width : 992px`)

Answer (score 0):

Привет!

 only screen - экран монитора

 а only handheld - смартфоны

P.S: Тут есть список для мобильных устройств - https://htmlweb.ru/css/media_screen.php